# Modify JavaScript object inside function, return to original if error

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I've got a JavaScript object in JSON format that needs to be modified based of a set input (delete foo or add bar, etc). This input can have cascading effects (delete foo might require foobar to be deleted first, based on a set of rules). If half way through a cascade something breaks I don't want the JavaScript object with half the modifications, I want to go back to the original unmodified object.

I could obviously just send a copy of the object into the modification function then not replace the original if the function returns an error. The issue with this is that the JavaScript object is around 25 megabytes, so a copy of it would mean a significant increase in memory usage by the browser. So I would like to do this without creating a copy of the object. I can just have the initial object be an input to the function and modify it recursively, but then if there is an error after some calls it could return a modified object when I don't want it to.

Would there be a way to do what I am trying to do? Keep track of the changes and easily undo them after an error, or something? Thanks.

Comment: "Write less Do more"!

Comment: My concern here is why do you have a javascript object of 25mb...

Comment: It sounds like you need to get your checks that return the original object done first, then follow up with your checks that actually modify the object.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Comment: Just throw the JS object away and reload the JSON from the browser cache

Comment: @taxicala It is a very unfortunate situation I will admit. It comes form reading in a 25MB JSON file that is a dump from a large database. As of right now there is not anything that can easily be done to break it up or shrink it, due to all the other code that interacts with it. Maybe in the future but I can't count on that right now.

Comment: I would do what @Bergi said, load the json and make sure to load it so that the browser caches it. then just get the json again and you have the object as it was before changing it.

Comment: @Bergi and taxicala I'll look into that as well as jfriend00's answer and see which one is best for my situation. Thanks!

Comment: @JediWolf: A 25MB database dump does not sound like something that you'd need to process every day, or even let your users do on the client. Do you really care about performance or memory usage at all?

Comment: @Bergi It probably wont be processed every day, but when it is run it might be run a few dozen times in a very short period of time (this unfortunately is not something I can control, I just have to work around it). Memory usage could be ignored, but the preference is that it is not (just copying it with no worry to memory is my fallback plan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create a transaction array that records each change made to the object and records enough data about the change such that it can be undone.  This is not a trivial amount of work to do.  It is somewhat similar to the undo capabilities in a word processor or spreadsheet for example.  If you record the right level of information and keep it in order in an array, it should be possible to reverse all the changes.  This is not rocket science, but it is a bit of code to write and test.

As mentioned in a comment, the larger question raised here is about a single 25MB object that has to be operated on by one function.  I'd personally wonder if you can break up the data into smaller pieces and be able to use smaller copies of things in order to not have to write this whole undo operation.

Also, it's worth considering whether you can pre-flight enough of the operations to know ahead of time whether the code will fail before you've modified the object or not.  For example, I've used code before that runs all the same logic as the code that modifies the object, but it doesn't actually modify the object.  This allows you to run a pre-flight of the entire operation and thus find out if anything fails some check before you've actually modified the object.  Written appropriately, you can use the same code for pre-flight as for actual modification with just an extra flag passed in.  How feasible this is depends upon the exact nature of the modification operation, something you haven't disclosed.

Here's an example of such code that handles changes to a specific object property.  This could be extended to include array manipulations too.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ohqL0p06/

Code:

```
function TransactionSummary() {
    this.transactions = [];
}

TransactionSummary.prototype = {
    deleteProperty: function(parent, property) {
        this.rememberTransaction(parent, property, "delete", parent[property]);
        delete parent[property];
    },
    modifyProperty: function(parent, property, newVal) {
        this.rememberTransaction(parent, property, "modify", parent[property]);
        parent[property] = newVal;
    },
    addProperty: function(parent, property, newVal) {
        this.rememberTransaction(parent, property, "add");
        parent[property] = newVal;
    },
    rememberTransaction: function(parent, property, type, oldVal) {
        this.transactions.push({parent: parent, property: property, type: type, oldVal: oldVal});
    },
    undoTransactions: function() {
        var t;
        while (this.transactions.length) {
            t = this.transactions.pop();
            switch(t.type) {
                case "delete":
                case "modify":
                    t.parent[t.property] = t.oldVal;
                    break;
                case "add":
                    delete parent[property];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately breaking the object up into smaller objects isn't really an option at this point in time. It's possible in the future time could be allotted to that, but it would require so much rewriting in other code that as of now the preferable choice would be to just copy the 25MB object and be memory heavy. I do admit it is a very odd situation, but it is what it is for now.

The transaction array option seems interesting, but using it would depend on how long it would take to create. Is there any good example of this out there (just similar enough to get an idea from looking at)?

Comment: @JediWolf - I added a sample of a transaction logger that can undo changes.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I'll have to see if I can get it to work on my end, but this is probably about the best I'll be able to get based on my circumstances.